# Why when I run sh -c [script], it won't accept any positional parameters?

Tags: shell

I am confused; I run a script, with sh -c , but if I want to pass a parameter, it will be ignored.

example:

```
# script.sh
param=$1
echo "parameter is: " $param
```

If I run it as

sh -c ./script.sh hello

I get nothing in the output

Why is this happening? How can I avoid this?

Comment: I can't; the process that span that command uses sh -c mandatory; I can't modify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
sh -c "./script.sh hello"
```

If you run it that way:

```
sh -c ./script.sh hello
```

than `hello` became `sh`'s second parameter and `./script.sh` is run with none parameters.

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand why this is happening...instead of considering the hello as $1 for the previous command, it consider it as a sh parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The `-c` switch accepts a single argument.  The shell will be doing the parsing itself.  E.g.

```
sh -c './script.sh hello'
```

Comment: Thanks! So the problem is the -c then; I need to see if I can remove it altogether.